# Fullscreen YouTube video crash

Tags: xorg, video, flash, crash

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

I was listening to this YouTube video: http://www.infinitelooper.com/?v=-tJYN-eG1zk&p=n

When I decided to make it full screen, but it didn't want to go, so I very quickly double-clicked on it twice, and then the entire screen went black. And no matter what I did, it go away. Although I could still hear the music from the video. As I couldn't do anything really about it I had to hold down my power button and force it to shutdown. And when it started up the screen was fine. It is a laptop so I don't think that the monitor just turned off or something.

I have filed a bug report here about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1413710

But I was just wondering if anyone here knows why this kind of thing could happen? And if it is actually a problem with my configuration settings and not actually a bug, or if it is a bug, then some sort of workaround.

---

**Information Update:**

As you will be able to see if you go to the place where I filed the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1413710), it has now been marked as `Confirmed` and `Critical`. And in the bug report comments you will see that this crash is not only caused by making YouTube videos fullscreen, but by making any page fullscreen.

Comment: **Except that is was a Queen video playing,** there seems to be nothing wrong with the page, running on Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-44-generic, FireFox 35.0, Shockwave Flash File: libflashplayer.so Path: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so Version: 11.2.202.429 State: Enabled Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202 *and is looping in the background as I'm typing this.*  ;-)

Comment: I'm running 14.10 and starting after todays updates my computer locks up if I full-screen a youtube video.

Comment: They have marked the bug as `Critical` so I am hope that it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome settings is the workaround I'm using for now. After disabling hardware acceleration, full-screen videos work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `Firefox` instead of `Chrome`. Though it is not a perfect solution, it works.

I got this idea from a similar question posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/577459/189148) (edit 2 in this question has this suggestion).

I am also waiting for a better solution for this question but for the time being, this sounds fine.