# Ubuntu MATE, Whole desktop crashes when exiting fullscreen video in chrome/chromium

Tags: compiz, ubuntu-mate

I have an issue where the whole desktop crashes when exiting fullscreen video in chrome/chromium. In particular it crashes when using Plex or Youtube for example.

The only way to solve it is too go to a tty and do a pkill -u username.

This happens in both chrome and chromium, but not in firefox.
It doesnt seem to happen if i run Macro instead of Compiz as a window manager.

It's extremely similar to this old question:
[Making youtube fullscreen will freeze Unity (the whole desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577459/making-youtube-fullscreen-will-freeze-unity-the-whole-desktop)

Except i'm running mate and not unity.

Anyone else have this / have a solution for this?

Comment: Unset hardware acceleration in the configuration of chrome / chromium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I've got this problem too, I can untick hardware acceleration however then Chrome become pretty unusable...there might be a setting in the flags I've turned on which is making this happen?

I'm running Unity though.

Comment: This worked for me! Actually i activated it shortly after asking the question but wanted some time to really test it before i flagged as solved! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also got this problem and it bothered me for a while. Then I found that clearing the compiz cache at `~/.cache/compizconfig-1/` and `~/.compiz` solved the problem temporarily.
Finally, disabling *Unredirect Fullscreen Windows* option in *Composite* plugin of CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) solved it.
CCSM isn't installed by default in Ubuntu. To install it type the following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Hope it solves for you too.