# Google Chrome Fullscreen - Display freezes

Tags: drivers, nvidia, google-chrome, nvidia-optimus, fullscreen

I have a HP Pavilion 15 au004tx with a Optimus video configuration (Nvidia GeForce 940MX + Intel HD Graphics 520) and Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.
When I am displaying a video in fullscreen mode, the screen freezes (the sound is still playing). I have been  looking for a solution on the internet and found out that I should turn off hardware acceleration on Chrome, but when I do that and turn a video to fullscreen mode, all the reds become blue and it still freezes, I think there is a driver issue.

Is there any known solution?

P.S: I have Bumblebee installed.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin please read my question, I have tried that and got an unexpected result. I am using Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: my bad. Does this occur for both your gpus? Also, can you play on fullscreen on firefox?

Comment: @SirajusSalekin on Firefox everything works ok. I don't know if that occurs for both GPUs since I don't know which GPU it's using.

Comment: ok, i'm just saying on a hunch. Type `chrome://flags` in chrome, enable `Override software rendering list`, restart chrome and test.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin tested that, it goes back to the first behavior where the screen will freeze (without the reds turning blue)

Comment: install inxi by `sudo apt-get install inxi` then update your post with the result of `inxi -G`

Comment: @SirajusSalekin
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 520
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 driver: N/A
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7

Comment: do you have device drivers installed? your `inxi -G` result should show `driver: intel` or `driver: nvidia` like [this](https://imgur.com/a/3SzxN), but it shows `driver: N/A`. As a temporary fix for chrome, you can try [the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/752067/529404)

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I tried the suggested solution, I have the same result... I don't know what's wrong. Is there any way I can remove the installed drivers? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I think it was a driver issue. I reinstalled my linux distribution, installed chrome and then went to chrome's settings and disabled hardware acceleration. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Post this answer below, and mark your q. as solved please.